# POSTMAN hangs on sending request in an express/Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, postman

I have a protected GET route to find and return a document from a MongoDb collection based on the logged in user id. I have created a middleware to just let the authenticated user access the route. When I test the route in postman it keeps sending request and never stops. It is definitely because of the authentication middleware, because when I disable the middleware the route works properly.
Here is my code for the route:

```
const getResearcherProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const profile = await Researcher.findOne({ user: req.user._id })
    res.json(profile)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500)
    throw new Error('Server error')
  }
})
```

The Researcher Model is as follow:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const researcherSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'users',
    },
    organization: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    researchFields: [
      {
        field: String,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

const Researcher = mongoose.model('researcher', researcherSchema)

export default Researcher
```

And here is the authentication middleware:

```
const protect = () => asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token

  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
  ) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]

      // decode the token
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select('-password')

      next()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      res.status(401)
      throw new Error('Not authorized, token failed')
    }
  }

  if (!token) {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('Not authorized, no token')
  }
})
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: What happens when you log inside, or step through, the middleware?

Comment: @DaveNewton By console log the req.user, it returns undefined, while the decoded.id returns an actual id. It seems that there is a problem with finding a document from users collection that makes the req.user undefined. But I can't find why!